# Anybody knows what the '2' matters in " sum(!is.na(HD[HD$VAL >= 24, 2])) "

Tags: r

When I used 2 or numbes above 0, the result is:

```
sum(!is.na(HD[HD$VAL >= 24, 1]))
# [1] 53
sum(!is.na(HD[HD$VAL >= 24, 2]))
# [1] 53
```

When I used nothing:

```
sum(!is.na(HD[HD$VAL >= 24, ]))
# [1] 9276
```

0

```
sum(!is.na(HD[HD$VAL >= 24, 0]))
# [1] 0
```

Why?

The sample Data is :

```
[1] 17 NA 18 19 20 15 NA NA 13  1 12 15 12 NA NA 17 15 11 NA NA NA  1 NA NA 17 13 NA  8 15 NA  8
[32] 16 22 11 14 19 10 NA 14 18 11 NA  8 12 20 NA  8 12 NA NA  6 15 NA 17 13 10 NA NA 21 17 14 NA
....
```

Comment: When you are using nothing, it is going through the whole dataset.  THe 1, 2 represents the columns selected.  In the first two cases, it subset the columns 1, 2, that correspond to 'VAL' greater than 24.  Then, we are converting to logical vector with `!is.na` and gettting the sum.  In that case, you have 53 non-NA values in the subset of that column 1 or 2.

Comment: The sample Data you showed looks like a `vector` and the code used is for a `matrix` or `data.frame`.

Comment: I think you can use `sum(!is.na(HD$VAL[HD$VAL >= 24]))` if you only want to sum the non NA values of VAL variable

Comment: please choose a better title so that someone else searching might find your question useful

Answer (score 3):

When you use a number in the second index, your code sums the values only in those columns

```
sum(!is.na(HD[HD$VAL >= 24, 1]))
```

This sums only column 1 where values are not NA.
When you leave the column index blank, all columns where the value is not NA will be summed.

Answer (score 2):

In `R`, indexing starts from 1 and not from 0.  So, using 0 to select the columns won't select anything and we get 0 as the output.

For the second part of the question, when we are not selecting any columns i.e. leaving the rhs of `,` as blank, it is selecting the the whole dataset columns.  The 1, 2 represents the columns selected.

In the first two cases, it subset the columns 1, 2, that correspond to 'VAL' greater than 24. Then, we are converting to logical vector with !is.na and getting the sum. In that case, you have 53 non-NA values in the subset of that column 1 or 2

i.e.

```
sum(!is.na(HD[HD$VAL >= 24, 1]))
```

---

However, we don't need to do this subsetting.  We can use `&`

```
sum(HD$VAL >==24 & !is.na(HD[,1]))
```

and similarly for the second column

```
sum(HD$VAL >==24 & !is.na(HD[,2]))
```